# Leave Management System(LMS) development on top of JBPM 5.3

Tags: jbpm

We are exploring the option of building a web based Leave Management System application on top of JBPM 5.3 . Basically we want to use our own user interfaces for our application as well as for the human tasks. The JBPM process should execute a new process instance in the background after getting triggered from our user interface and also get inputs for its human task data also similarly from our user interfaces. Can you please help us understanding the feasibility of such an application with JBPM 5.3 .

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect fit for jBPM5. Yes you can do it.. that's the idea of jBPM5. Any other specific question?
Cheers

Comment: Hi Salaboy,
Is there any sample project which is recommended by jbpm team?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your own user task module, and you need jbpm5 to interact with it,  then you can read about domain-specific processes: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.domain-specific-processes.html